# call subcontroller from view with ajax Joomla

Tags: jquery, joomla, url-routing

I would like to send an ajax request to one of my sub controllers method, but everything what I have been trying out doesn't seems to work. The request looks like

```
 ajax: {
                url: "index.php?option=com_mycomponent&controller=search&task=locator&tmpl=component&<?php echo JUtility::getToken() ?>=1",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: function(term, page) {
                    return {
                        q: term, // search term
                    };
                },
                results: function(data, page) {
                    return {results: data};
                }
```

**the controller**

```
class MyControllerControllerMyController extends JControllerLegacy
{


    function __construct($config = array()) {
        parent::__construct($config);
        echo 'test';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would call this URL: `index.php?option=com_mycomponent&task=search.locator&format=json&<?php echo JUtility::getToken() ?>=1`
Note that the task has two parts, the first one before the dot is the controller, the second the function. Also note the format parameter, this one tells Joomla to look for a file named `search.json.php` within the `controllers` directory.

The controller class has to be named `MycomponentControllerSearch`

Also the response needs to be json encoded. You can do this like this:
    $response = array(
        'status' => '0',
        'error' => JText::_('JINVALID_TOKEN'),
    );
    echo json_encode($response);

After the response is sent, use `JExit()` to terminate the script.

Comment: Please note that adding the token outside of a form will break if you enable page caching. If you create a standard form and add the hidden input field with JToken then it will work always.

Comment: @RiccardoZorn I'm not clear on what you're saying… what would it break  if you enable page caching?

Comment: He means that the token for the URL may be cached as well as part of the page, and thus the token will fail. But then caching is usually disabled as soon as a user is logged in (due to issues with userstates and such), so it shouldn't be a problem.